# Index out of range performing a Do While Loop

Tags: vb.net, do-while

I'm trying to perform an iterative calculus through Do while/until Loop. I set it but while debugging I'm receiving back this error: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.` This is the code I'm using:

```
t=0    
Do While TEMsprinkler(t) < CInt(TextBox12.Text)
            t += 1
            TEMsprinkler(t + 1) = (TEMsprinkler(t) + ((tjet(t + 1) - TEMsprinkler(t)) * (1 - Math.Exp(-1 / tau(t + 1)))) + ((tjet(t + 1) - tjet(t)) * t * ((Math.Exp(-1 / tau(t + 1))) - (1 / tau(t + 1)) - 1)))
Loop
```

Now, I can't understand where the error could be: TEMsprinkler(t) is declared (as a boundary condition to start the iteration); the other variables (list of double) have been already declared and filled with positive numbers. Where am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance. Best regards.

---

**Edit:**
I've tried to edit my code in several ways. Since I'm working with List(Of Double) and not with arrays, I edited the TEMsprinkler line as follows:

```
Do While TEMsprinkler(t) < CInt(TextBox12.Text)
     t += 1
     TEMsprinkler.Add(TEMsprinkler(t) + ((tjet(t + 1) - TEMsprinkler(t)) * (1 - Math.Exp(-1 / tau(t + 1)))) + ((tjet(t + 1) - tjet(t)) * t * ((Math.Exp(-1 / tau(t + 1))) - (1 / tau(t + 1)) - 1)))
Loop
```

I'm having back the same error. Then I tried to edit index position: t+1 index became t and t index became t-1 position and starting to increment t from 1 and no more from 0 but I have always the out-bounds error.

---

**Edit II:** As suggested, I edited my code, declaring separed variables and the issue seems to be on the Do While line:

```
t=1
Do While TEMsprinkler(t) < CInt(TextBox12.Text)
    t += 1
    Dim TSPKITEM = TEMsprinkler(t)
    Dim TJITEM = tjet(t)
    Dim ITEMTJ = tjet(t + 1)
    Dim TAUITEM = tau(t + 1)
    TEMsprinkler.Add(TSPKITEM + ((ITEMTJ - TSPKITEM) * (1 - Math.Exp(-1 / TAUITEM))) + ((ITEMTJ - TJITEM) * t * ((Math.Exp(-1 / TAUITEM)) - (1 / TAUITEM) - 1)))
Loop
```

Obviously the error is always the same.

---

**Edit III:***
I've built three different List(of Double), with their lower boundary condition, that are gonna need me to do the iterations. The dimension of these lists are major than the CInt(Textbox12.Text) value. Then I declared the Do While Loop to build TEMsprinkler variable (declared as List(of Double) too). Here is the code:

```
Dim tjet As New List(Of Double)()
Dim ujet As New List(Of Double)()
Dim tau As New List(Of Double)()
Dim TEMsprinkler As New List(Of Double)()
Dim t As Integer
t = 1
TEMsprinkler.Add(CDbl(TextBox8.Text))
tjet.Add(CDbl(TextBox8.Text))
ujet.Add(0)
tau.Add(0)
For i = 1 To CInt(Form3.ListBox1.Items.Count) - 1
     tjet.Add(CDbl(TextBox8.Text) + (5.38 * ((CDbl(Form3.ListBox1.Items(i)) / r) ^ 0.666) / h))
     ujet.Add(0.197 * (CDbl(Form3.ListBox1.Items(i)) ^ 0.333) * (h ^ 0.5) / r ^ 0.833)
     tau.Add((CInt(TextBox2.Text) / (ujet(i) ^ 0.5)))
Next
Do While t < TEMsprinkler.Count - 1 AndAlso TEMsprinkler(t) < CInt(TextBox12.Text)
    t += 1
    Dim TSPKITEM = TEMsprinkler(t)
    Dim TJITEM = tjet(t)
    Dim ITEMTJ = tjet(t + 1)
    Dim TAUITEM = tau(t + 1)
    TEMsprinkler.Add(TSPKITEM + ((ITEMTJ - TSPKITEM) * (1 - Math.Exp(-1 / TAUITEM))) + ((ITEMTJ - TJITEM) * t * ((Math.Exp(-1 / TAUITEM)) - (1 / TAUITEM) - 1)))
Loop
```

Comment: Once you get to the end of your collection, you'd get an index out of range exception because you're incrementing the value of `t` but immediately afterwards, getting `TEMsprinkler(t + 1)`. Remove the `+ 1` and you should be good.

Comment: @David thanks for commenting. I edited my answer considering your suggestion.

Comment: Try separating the values into variables so that when the exception gets thrown, you know exactly where it gets thrown. E.g.:
`Dim temSprinnklerItem = TEMsprinkler(t)
Dim tjetItem = tjet(t + 1)
Dim tauItem = tau(t + 1)
'etc...`

Comment: @David I edited my post again. Unfortunately always getting same error.

Comment: I figured you'd get the same error, but what line is the error occurring on?

Comment: It is on the Do While line, the second line of the code reported in Edit II.

Comment: In that case you'll need to setup an additional conditional check that happens before your original one. `Do While TEMsprinkler.Count - 1 < t AndAlso TEMsprinkler(t) < CInt(TextBox12.Text)`

Comment: Same error again, even with this additional check. It occurs on the same line of the previous case.

Comment: My apologies, I had it backwards. It should be: `t < TEMsprinkler.Count - 1`

Comment: Ok now it is running. I mean that I'm not having more that error. The problem now is that it stops at the first iteration.

Comment: Then that means that your collection only has a single item in it. Could you elaborate on what it is that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: How many elements do you have in your arrays, and what would be an example value of TextBox12.Text?

Comment: @Hursey Arrays have approximately 2000 as value of size. Textbox12.Text is 68. I edited my answer, hoping to be clearer in what I want to have.

Comment: I also verified through two listboxes that tjet and ujet have been built correctly and size values are correct.